# how to get an object and invoke a method in jstl EL in a JSP

Tags: jsp, el

I'm trying to convert the following scriptlet code to EL. I tried the following (below), but can't get it working.  getValue() is a method off of ConfigFactory that returns a string:

In a listener, I set the configFactory as `event.getServletContext().setAttribute("ConfigFactory", new ConfigFactory());`

In my scriptlet code there is: (and it works fine)

```
<% 
  ConfigFactory cf = (ConfigFactory) application.getAttribute("ConfigFactory");
%>
Value from scriptlet= <%=cf.getValue()%> <br/>
```

EL gives me trouble:

```
<c:set var="cf" value="${initParam['ConfigFactory']}"/>
<c:out value="${cf.getValue}"/>  <!-- try # 1 -->
<c:out value="${cf.value}"/>     <!-- try # 2 -->
```

Comment: `${cf.value}` _should_ work. What happens when you try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
<c:set var="cf" value="${initParam['ConfigFactory']}"/>
```

does basically the same as

```
pageContext.setAttribute("cf", application.getInitParameter("ConfigFactory"));
```

You don't want this. Get rid of that line. In EL, you have implicitly direct access to all request, session and application attributes by just its name. The following

```
${ConfigFactory}
```

does basically the same as

```
out.print(pageContext.findAttribute("ConfigFactory"));
```

The [`PageContext#findAttribute()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) tests respectively `PageContext#getAttribute()`, `HttpServletRequest#getAttribute()`, `HttpSession#getAttribute()` and finally `ServletContext#getAttribute()` until the first non-null value is been found. This is more what you want.

You can finally access the `getValue()` method on it the usual EL way:

```
${ConfigFactory.value}
```

Not related to the problem, but you'd normally give instance identifiers a name starting with lowercase. You also don't do `ConfigFactory ConfigFactory = new ConfigFactory();`, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
${applicationScope.ConfigFactory.value}
```